# Javascript and session variables

Tags: javascript, session

I have a database that stores events in it and a page with a calendar object on it. When rendering the days it looks through the months events and if any match the current day being rendered it creates a linkbutton to represent the event in the day on the calendar and adds it to that cell. I add some javascript to the linkbutton to change the window.location to a page to view event details passing EventID in the querystring ( I tried setting the postbackurl of the newly created linkbutton but it wasnt causing a postback... no luck). I need to set a Session variable ie. Session("EditMode") = "Edit" So the new page will know it is to get an existing event info rather than prepare to create a new event? Any SUGGESTIONS?

Comment: What events are you storing? And also, could you post some code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your session vars are controlled by the server,
JS runs client side, and as such cannot modify the vars directly.

You need to make server requests using POST or GET and hidden
iframes, or XMLHTTPRequest() calls to send data from the JS to
the server, and then have your server side code handle the vars.

Add another query string variable that the page can use to trigger existing vs new.

Answer (score 6):

Add another query string variable that the page can use to trigger existing vs new.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using something like Struts2, you can have a hidden variable in your jsp

```
<s:hidden id="EditModeId" value="%{#session.EditMode}"/>
```

And within javascript simply access this variable

```
alert(document.getElementById('EditModeId').value);
```

Answer (score 1):

You definitely need to add a variable to the target page.  But I take it that you are doing a popup scenario, so you should be able to create a javascript function OpenWindow() and fire it off when the user clicks the link.

```
<script>
function OpenWindow(eventId, editMode)
{
    var window = window.open("popup.aspx?eventId=" + eventId + "&editMode=" + editMode);
}
</script>
```

On the server side you need to build the call to the OpenWindow function.  For example:

```
onclick="OpenWindow(eventId=" + row["eventId"].ToString() + "&editMode=" + editMode.ToString() + ");"
```

So in other words, prep everything on the serverside to set your javascript to post all variables to the new page.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
var page1 = document.getElementById("textbox").value; 
sessionStorage.setItem("page1content", page1);
```

in other page use this value as like session variable

```
document.getElementById("textbox2").value=sessionStorage.getItem("page1content");
```